# From Chek Lap Kok Airport to Macau via the mega bridge

Tags: hong-kong, macau, singaporean-citizens

I heard that arrangements can be made at HKIA Terminal 2 for a car/van to take our group of 8 to Macau.  What is the procedure to make this arrangement so that we can see and enjoy going through the new mega bridge?

Answer (score 1):

According to Hong Kong International Airport's website, [coaches](https://www.hongkongairport.com/en/transport/mainland-connection/mainland-coaches/) and [limo](https://www.hongkongairport.com/en/transport/mainland-connection/skylimo.page) services to/from Macau are available:

> Coaches provide a convenient method of transportation between Mainland China/ Macao and Hong Kong International Airport.
>
> Services are available at the Mainland/ Macao Transport Centre of Terminal 2 for travel to destinations such as ... Macao ... via different cross-boundary land control points.

and

> SkyLimo provides convenient door to door deluxe services between Hong Kong International Airport (HKIA) and Mainland China. Chauffeurs are professional, courteous and proficient in English. Please make your bookings in advance to prevent any delays.
>
> Tour and travel packages to ... Macao are also available. Please check with individual service providers for more details.

You can obtain information or book by walking up to the counters in:

> Mainland/ Macao Transport Centre, Arrivals Level (L3), Terminal 2

... which in my opinion is comparable to how you rent a car airports.

or as suggested by the quoted website, enquire and book services operated by the four service providers in advance by 1) calling the numbers or 2) using the enquiry form listed on the website. Make sure to include the requirement that you wanted to go via the Hong Kong-Zhuhai-Macau Bridge.